# Unix looping from text file

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have 2 text files. I want to loop in the first file to get a list, then using that list, loop from the second file to search for matching fields.

The first loop was fine, but when the second loop comes in, the variable `$CLIENT_ABBREV` cannot be read in the second loop, it's reading as blank. Output looks like `does not match DOG` where there's a blank before `does`.

```
while IFS=',' read CLIENT_ID NAME SERVER_NAME CLIENT_ABBREV
do
    echo "\n------------"
    echo Configuration in effect for this run
    echo CLIENT_ID=$CLIENT_ID
    echo NAME=$NAME
    echo SERVER_NAME=$SERVER_NAME
    echo CLIENT_ABBREV=$CLIENT_ABBREV

    while IFS=',' read JOB_NAME CLIENT_ABBREV_FROMCOMMAND JOBTYPE JOBVER
    do
    if [ "$CLIENT_ABBREV" == "$CLIENT_ABBREV_FROMCOMMAND" ]; then
        # do something
    else
       echo $CLIENT_ABBREV does not match $CLIENT_ABBREV_FROMCOMMAND
    done <"$COMMAND_LIST"

done <"$CLIENT_LIST"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a file with the name COMMAND_LIST ?

Or, actually do you want to use $COMMAND_LIST  instead of COMMAND_LIST   ?

Comment: Yup there's a file for COMMAND_LIST, that's the second file where I want to search for matching field

Comment: Since CLIENT_LIST is a variable, what I mean is that .. does COMMAND_LIST a variable ?  If yes, please use $COMMAND_LIST

Comment: AH! Silly me. I forgot the $ on that one. Worked after putting that in. Thanks.

Comment: @dixienormous Please accept the answer before other people are looking for a solution. And ypu might upvote the answer too,

Comment: @WalterA I ran into a new error. So I made some adjustment to the question. Alvin SIU's answer helped.

Comment: this is not a chatbox with changing questions. The first question was solved, so rollback your edits in the question and accept this one. New problems can be placed in a new question. For the problem you have now, please add the contents of the input files and the output of the `echo`'s. It looks like the line causing the error doesn't has 4 fields, maybe your inpus has an empty line. Don't discuss that here, debug more and post a new question with your debug info when you are stuck.